Cómo puedo en el siguiente código poner numero de persona (como va el contador) y su costo en la parte inferior del programa? Qdando costo gral e ind
costo = 0
contador = 0
entrada = input("Escribe la edad del invitado (linea en blanco para terminar): ")

while (entrada != ""):
    edad = int(entrada)
    if edad <= 0 :
        print("Error: edad invalida")
    elif edad <= 2:
        costo0 = 0
        costo += 0
        contador +=1


    elif edad>2 and edad <12:
        costo1 = 20
        costo += 20
        contador +=1

    elif edad >65:
        costo2 = 0
        costo += 0
        contador +=1

    elif edad >= 12 and edad <= 65:
        costo3 = 40
        costo += 40
        contador +=1

    entrada = input("Escribe la edad del invitado (linea en blanco para terminar): ")
print("Linea en blanco escrita fin del programa")
print("El costo de admision del grupo que consta de" ,contador, "personas es de: %0.2f" 
%costo)

Ocupa solo conocimientos que esten en este codigo, sin filas, solo cosas basicas, ya que no se pide más que eso.
Al poner el costo individual este puede ser en formato de lista o los costos pueden estar en una sola linea. Un ejemplo puede ser: el costo de la persona (contador) es de (costo).

Veamos como podemos alcanzar el objetivo, introduciendo unas pequeñas modificaciones a tu código.
contador = 0

# cambiamos nombre, para diferenciarlo del individdual
costoTotal = 0

# creamos una lista para guardar los costos individuales
costoIndividual = []

mensaje =  "Escribe la edad del invitado (linea en blanco para terminar): "
entrada = input( mensaje )

while( entrada != "" ):
    edad = int( entrada )

    # como puedes ver, modifiqué los "if" para que todos evaluaran con "<",
    # ya que, en mi modesta opinión, hace la lectura más clara y evita errores
    if edad < 1:
        print( "Error: edad invalida" )
        
    elif edad < 3:
        costoIndividual[ 0 ] = 0
        costoTotal += 0
        contador +=1


    elif edad < 12:
        costoIndividual[ 1 ] = 20
        costoTotal += 20
        contador +=1

    # dado el cambio en los "if", es necesario alterar el orden de los mismos
    elif edad < 65:
        costoIndividual[ 3 ] = 40
        costoTotal += 40
        contador +=1

    else:
        costoIndividual[ 2 ] = 0
        costoTotal += 0
        contador +=1
    
    entrada = input( mensaje )
    
print( "Linea en blanco escrita fin del programa" )
print( "El costo de admision del grupo que consta de ", contador, " personas es de: %0.2f" 
% costoTotal )

Si quieres mostrar los costos individuales, puedes usar:
i = 0
while( i < len( costoIndividual ) ):
    print( costoIndividual[ i ] )
    i += 1

